# Laravel Eloquent REPLACE

Tags: mysql, laravel, command, eloquent

I'm creating a database migration script in a Laravel 4 command.

All the database migration process is fine but I'm having trouble changing user prefixes: I need to change USER-JOHN-JB TO USER-JOHN-OD, all the user suffixes need to be changes from '-JB' to '-OD'.

The current line of code I have is:

```
DB::table('users')->update(['username' => DB::raw("REPLACE(username, '-".$suffix."', '-".$thisSuffix."')")]);
```

If I run this code in the REPL it works fine however it doesn't work in the command.

Looking at the logs the generated SQL query is:

```
update `users` set `username` = REPLACE(username, "-JB
", "-OD")
```

For some reason a line break is being inserted into the query. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the problem.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$suffix`? It seems to have a newline character in it.

Comment: $suffix should just be '-JB', I'll check out if there is a new line

Comment: You are right. For info the code for suffix was like this:

$result = array_reverse(explode('-', $result));
$suffix = $result[0];

Adding a trim around the result fixed the problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben Harold pointed out, the problem came from $suffix containing a line break. Adding trim() fixed the problem.